# Construction of an additive compound matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

I want to construct an additive compound matrix which has the following form as output :

```
ACM = {{a11 + a22, a23, -a13}, {a32, a33 + a11, a12}, {-a31, a32, 
   a33 + a22}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the starting point? What are the rules that generate this matrix?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you made a typo in `ACM[[3,2]]`, and meant `a21` instead of `a32`, your `ACM` is the generic form of the additive compound matrix of a $3\times 3 $ matrix (I took the definitions from [this pdf](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Emathirl/IUSEP/IUSEP_2019/lecture_notes/compound_ula.pdf)):

```
CalcACM[matrix_, k_] := D[Minors[IdentityMatrix[Length@matrix] + t*matrix, k], t] /. t -> 0

mGeneric = {
  {b11, b12, b13},
  {b21, b22, b23},
  {b31, b32, b33}
}

CalcACM[mGeneric,2]
(* {{b11 + b22, b23, -b13}, {b32, b11 + b33, b12}, {-b31, b21, b22 + b33}} *)
```

Comment: Dear Hausdorff, thank you so much for your response and for sharing the reference of Muldowney as well. :)