# My construction of additive compound matrices doesn't work sometimes; why?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

Using the multiplicative compound matrix --see definition at [Are compound matrices implemented in mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261782/are-compound-matrices-implemented-in-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment651840_261782)

one may define also additive compound matrices

```
(*Multiplicative compound matrix*)
MulCMat[A_?MatrixQ, k_Integer] := 
  Module[{m, n, p, q}, {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
   p = Subsets[Range[1, m], {k}];
   q = Subsets[Range[1, n], {k}];
   Table[Det[A[[i, j]]], {i, p}, {j, q}]];
A = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
Print["Wiki example of multiplicative compound", 
 MulCMat[A, 2] // MatrixForm]

(*Additive compound matrix*)
AdCMat[A_, k_Integer] := 
  Module[{m, Id}, m = Length[A]; Id = IdentityMatrix[m]; 
   Limit[Simplify[MulCMat[Id + t A, k] - MulCMat[Id, k]]/t, t -> 0]];
A = {{a11, a12, a13}, {a21, a22, a23}, {a31, a32, a33}};
Print["Second additive compound ", AdCMat[A, 2] // MatrixForm]
```

Unfortunately, my program does not work on the matrix I have, which is

```
ja = {{-e \[Beta]e - \[Gamma]r - \[Gamma]s - \[CapitalLambda] + 
     i (-\[Beta] + \[Nu]), -s \[Beta]e - \[Gamma]r, -\[Gamma]r + 
     s (-\[Beta] + \[Nu])}, {i \[Beta] + e \[Beta]e, 
    s \[Beta]e - \[Gamma]e - \[CapitalLambda] + i \[Nu], 
    s \[Beta] + e \[Nu]}, {0, 
    ei, -\[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] + (-1 + 2 i) \[Nu]}};
AdCMat[ja, 2]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: How does additive compound matrix make any sense for nonsquare matrices?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It may not. I have not checked this in the reference mentioned below, since I only need this in the square case,  for estimating stability of systems of ODEs.  https://www.researchgate.net/profile/James-Muldowney-2/publication/38372479_Compound_matrices_and_ordinary_differential_equations/links/58b1b9a8aca2725b5416ed5f/Compound-matrices-and-ordinary-differential-equations.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the multiplicative compound matrix using `Minors` (which is also mentioned in the comment by Daniel Lichtblau to your linked [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261782/73380))

```
B = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {10, 10}];
MulCMat[B, 5] === Minors[B, 5]
(* True *)
```

It is also more efficient to define the additive compound matrix via a derivative, which is what your `Limit[_,t->0]` is trying to do (see also my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262053/73380))

```
CalcACM[matrix_, k_] := D[Minors[IdentityMatrix[Length@matrix] + t*matrix, k], t] /. t -> 0
```

This gives you for your matrix `ja`

```
CalcACM[ja, 2]
(* {
    {-e \[Beta]e + s \[Beta]e - \[Gamma]e - \[Gamma]r - \[Gamma]s -  2 \[CapitalLambda] + i \[Nu] + i (-\[Beta] + \[Nu]),  s \[Beta] + e \[Nu], \[Gamma]r - s (-\[Beta] + \[Nu])},
    {ei, -e \[Beta]e - \[Gamma] - \[Gamma]r - \[Gamma]s - 2 \[CapitalLambda] + (-1 + 2 i) \[Nu] +  i (-\[Beta] + \[Nu]), -s \[Beta]e - \[Gamma]r},
    {0, i \[Beta] + e \[Beta]e, s \[Beta]e - \[Gamma] - \[Gamma]e - 2 \[CapitalLambda] + i \[Nu] + (-1 + 2 i) \[Nu]}
} *)
```

**Edit**

The reason why your code failed is due to a reuse of the symbol `i`, which appears both as a variable in `ja` and as a `Table` iterator in `MulCMat`. To avoid such problems, the iterators used for `Table` should be made local in `Module` as well, i.e.

```
MulCMat[A_?MatrixQ, k_Integer] := 
Module[{m, n, p, q, i, j}, {m, n} = Dimensions[A];
  p = Subsets[Range[1, m], {k}];
  q = Subsets[Range[1, n], {k}];
  Table[Det[A[[i, j]]], {i, p}, {j, q}]
];
```

After making this change, `AdCMat[ja,2]` and `CalcACM[ja,2]` give the same result.